# Краш приложения с toolbar

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать чтоб toolbar скрывался при прокручивании, не выходит и крашится.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    <имя пакета>MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
```

строка 54 :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

tool_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы как минимум используете несуществующий id - `(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);`. `tool_bar` в вашем XML нету.

---

Т. К. вы решили скрывать от нас подробности, то я попробую погадать на кофейной гуще:

добавьте к тулбару айдишник:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         android:id="@+id/realToolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

И ищите сам тулбар по настоящему айдишнику:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.realToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: tool_bar.xml это и есть сам файл, он инклюдится в main активити

Comment: @АндрейУжегов, Да, точно, простите, что не воспользовался телепатией, чтобы узнать это.

Comment: @АндрейУжегов, значит в этом и проблема. Уберите Id у Include и перенесите его в тулбар

Answer (score 0):

У вас в разметке нет у тулюара ID-шника. Скорее всего из-за этого эта странная проблема

---

> tool_bar.xml это и есть сам файл, он инклюдится в main активити

значит в этом и проблема. Уберите Id у Include и перенесите его в тулбар

Comment: Уже и задавал, все равно также

Comment: @АндрейУжегов, у вас в ошибкке вообще сказано, что вы пытаетесь коллапс к тулюару скастовать. Проверьте ещё раз все айди